# Search does not works in codeigniter with pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination

I am trying to add search in my lists. I am using codeigniter and pagination for listing. The search is just the database search as a sample id . The search works perfect in the first page of pagination.  But when it comes to other pages it does not work.

This is the code for my controller.

```
  $this->clear_sample_id_catche();
  $out=$this->Mgeneral->listData();
  $per_page = 10;
  $total = $this->Mgeneral->countData();
  $data = $this->Mgeneral->listData($per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));

   $base_url = site_url('general/listData');

   $config['base_url'] = $base_url;
   $config['total_rows'] = $total;
   $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
   $config['uri_segment'] = '3';

  $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
  $data=array('body'=>'list','out'=>$data);

  $this->load->view('template',$data);
```

I added form to search in my view.
Can any one suggest my what the problem is??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont see any search parameters in your code and i think this is the problem you might be using it through post data but codeigniters pagination is redirection base so you lose the search parameters on next request.

Comment: for pagination with search, you either have to use a get method or store the posted search parameter in a hidden field in your form, so the next page will carry along the search parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be forgetting to pass the search query for the pagination. Seeing how the page number is the third segment of the query string, I'm guessing that the search form will do a `POST` action when it gets submitted by the user. After the user submitted the form, of course it will work. Because they just did a `POST` request, and you fetch the search query from `$_POST` by using `$this->input->post('user_input')` or something similar. But then, when they try to navigate to another page by clicking on the page number link (which is a `GET` request), the search fails because the superglobal `$_POST` array is empty.

A solution to solve this problem is to set a session value (I recommend that you use CodeIgniter's Session Class) based on the user input and instead of using the search query from `$_POST`, and use the one stored in session instead.

Another way you can do it, is to make another page for the search result (assuming it is currently in the same page as the form, i.e. in the same controller function). Then make the search form do a `GET` request to its own controller function which will then encode the search query in `base64`, and replace the `=` (equal sign) from the encoded string with a `.`. After that, redirect the user to the search result page while passing the encoded search query as the third segment in the URL query string (the page number will be the fourth). And in that function replace the `.` back to `=` and use `base64_decode()` to get the search query and pass it to the function that will generate the search result.

Of course, there are lots of other ways to achieve the same result. Just google it.

Comment: Thanks every one I used get method and now I solved my problem. Thank you so much for the help.