# Codeigniter Search Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, search, pagination

I'm working on some search engine and I would like to have nice pagination, but it looks this is no go with POST type. I've some form in which is entered query for searching and after form is sended, there are some results. The first page of results is normally and work, but if I click on any other page in my pagination there is no results, because the POST input value is nowhere stored. I've already tried to do my search with GET like - to add query in URL, but this is also not possible because CodeIgniter dont't allow some characters which are in urlencode. I was also looking for encoding the query string with base64, but it also looks this is no way because there are some unallowed characters again.

What I have to do instead all of these?

Comment: Read the third paragraph of the answer (about the base64 encoding), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169853/search-does-not-works-in-codeigniter-with-pagination/10170227#10170227

Comment: I've already read this, but as I mentioned there's problem with disallowed characters. Example: search string: `today isn't sunny !\"#$%&/()==?*)` and after base64 encode it becomes `dG9kYXkgaXNuJ3Qgc3VubnkgISIjJCUmLygpPT0/Kik=` which also contains disallowed character (if we replace = with some allowed character)

Comment: Just like what I said in that answer, replace the `=` with a `.`. That should fix the problem.

Comment: If I encode this string `string with special characters 2342356B %$&$% $%& GFD FD;:_ -.,, žćđšč QWERExycxfdSFHGstring with special characters 2342356B %$&$% $%& GFD FD;:_ -.,, žćđšč QWERExycxfdSFHGstring with special characters 2342356B %$&$% $%& GFD FD;:_ -.,, žćđšč QWERExycxfdSFHG ` or some like that, after encoding I get + which is disallowed character... Is this only when is string longer than xy characters or it can be random?

Comment: Yes. If the string was shorter, the encoded string will be padded with `=`. So the characters you have to watch out for is `+`, `/`, and `=`. You can replace `+` with `_`, `=` with `.`, and `/` with `-`. See wikipedia for more info about this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history

Comment: You can ajax pagination. After every request, you can store the criteria and post it again inside your function. By this, you can get results when you do next page click.

Comment: Are these all characters which I must watch out or it can be some others there? Edit: I don't want to use Ajax because this will be public search (what means there will be more traffic to server)

Comment: Yes, those 3 characters are the special characters you have to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks, could you please add new answer with content as your previous comment because I want to accept your solution as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the POST data into GET data (e.g. as URL parameters, see [*Query part* of the URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) and [*Variables From External Sources* in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)) or you store the search into the session and only pass along a search identifier so that you can retrieve the search's POST data from session.

Answer (score 0):

```
Search with Pagination in Codeingter

Step 1 : Created search_results.php in view
  <?php include ('public_header.php');?>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Serach Results</h1>
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <td>Sr No.</td>
      <td>Article Title</td>
      <td>Published On</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
    <?php if(count($articles)):?>
     <?php $count=$this->uri->segment(4,0);?>
     <?php foreach($articles as $article ):?>
      <td><?= ++$count?></td>
      <td><?= $article->title?></td>
      <td><?= "Date" ?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php endforeach;?>

    <?php else: ?>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="3"> No Records Found.</td>
     </tr>
     <?php endif;?>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <?= $this->pagination->create_links();?>
  </div>

  <?php include ('public_footer.php');?>

step 2 created function in controller

  public function search()
  {
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('query','Query','required');

   if(! $this->form_validation->run())
    $this->index();

   $query=$this->input->post('query');
   return redirect("user/search_results/$query");

   // $this->load->view('public/search_results',compact('articles'));
  }

  public function search_results($query)
  {
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->model('articlesmodel','articles');
   $this->load->library('pagination');
   $config=[
     'base_url'  => base_url("user/search_results/$query"),
     'per_page'   => 5,
     'total_row'  => $this->articles->count_search_results($query),
     'full_tag_open' => "<ul class='pagination'>",
     'full_tag_close'=> "</ul>",
     'first_tag_opne' => "<li>",
     'first_tag_close'=> "</li>",
     'uri_segment'  => 4,
     // 'first_link'  => "<li>"
     // 'last_link'   => "</li>"
     'last_tag_opne' => "<li>",
     'last_tag_close' => "</li>",
     'next_tag_opne' => "<li>",
     'next_tag_close' => "</li>",
     'pre_tag_open'  => "<li>",
     'pre_tag_close' => "</li>",
     'num_tag_open'  => '<li>',
     'num_tag_close' => '</li>',
     'cur_tag_open'  => "<li class='active'><a>",
     'cur_tag_close' => '</a></li>',
   ];

   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $articles=$this->articles->search($query,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
   $this->load->view('public/search_results',compact('articles'));
  }

Step 3 :Created function in model

  public function search($query,$limit,$offset)
  {
   $q=$this->db->from('articles')
      ->like('title',$query)
      ->limit($limit,$offset)
      ->get();
   return $q->result();
  }
  public function count_search_results($query)
  {
   $q=$this->db->from('articles')
     ->like('title',$query)
     ->get();
   return $q->num_rows();
  }
```